# THREE.js transparent plane cutting adjacent object texture

Tags: three.js, alpha-transparency

[transcut http://glasier.hk/image/transcut.png](http://glasier.hk/image/transcut.png)

Each face is made with this:

```
geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(w,h,1,1,1);
base = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: pass.color, transparent: true, side: THREE.DoubleSide} )
material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(pass.img), transparent: true, opacity:1, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
shape = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

What have I done wrongly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like a depth buffer issue.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165345/three-js-webgl-transparent-planes-hiding-other-planes-behind-them) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763603/transparent-textures-behaviour-in-webgl).

You can try playing with the depthTest and depthWrite parameters of your material or draw the objects in a custom order. You can do this by setting `renderer.sortObjects = false` and adding to the scene the transparent textures last.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I used `alphaTest: 0.5` as Mr Doob suggested in "this". God bless his cotton socks.